# Style react-select with aphrodite

Tags: reactjs, react-select, aphrodite

I'm trying to use some existing styles built in aphrodite to style a 3rd party component react-select.  The component has some props on it that allow you to pass a className that defines the class to use for the main container of the component. It then has a classNamePrefix prop that is used to prefix the child items in the component. The documentation details what combination of classNamePrefix + name to use in your style sheet to style each item.

https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames

I'm looking for an example of how I'd do this using aphrodite. The issue I'm having is when I call css(), I get a random class name. I can't figure out a way  to specify the classNamePrefix.

Comment: aphrodite doesn't let you use descendant selectors (https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite/issues/10) so setting `classNamePrefix` won't be that helpful. You would have to replace the inner components yourself (https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the React Select [Component](https://react-select.com/components) API Here is a sample of how I used Aphrodite to inject custom styles in to individual sections of the React Select component.

```
// Node Modules
import { css } from 'aphrodite';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactSelect, { components } from 'react-select';
// Styles
import styles from './SelectStyles';
import { fontStyles } from 'styles';
// Assets
import caretImg from 'images/downCaret.svg';

class Select extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { noOptionsMessage, onChange, options, value } = this.props;

    const Control = props => (
      <components.Control {...props} className={css(styles.selectControl)} />
    );

    const DropdownIndicator = props => {
      return (
        components.DropdownIndicator && (
          <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
            <img src={caretImg} height="6px" alt="▼" className={css(styles.caret)} />
          </components.DropdownIndicator>
        )
      );
    };

    const IndicatorSeparator = ({ innerProps }) => {
      return <span className={css(styles.indicatorSeparator)} {...innerProps} />;
    };

    const Menu = props => {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <components.Menu {...props} className={css(styles.menu)}>
            {props.children}
          </components.Menu>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };

    const Option = props => (
      <components.Option
        {...props}
        className={css(
          fontStyles.regular,
          props.isSelected ? styles.menuOptionSelected : styles.menuOption,
        )}
      />
    );

    const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>{children}</components.ValueContainer>
    );

    return (
      <ReactSelect
        className={css(fontStyles.semibold, styles.selectContainer)}
        components={{
          Control,
          DropdownIndicator,
          IndicatorSeparator,
          Menu,
          Option,
          ValueContainer,
        }}
        isSearchable={true}
        noOptionsMessage={() => noOptionsMessage}
        onChange={onChange}
        options={options}
        value={value}
      />
    );
  }
}

Select.propTypes = {
  noOptionsMessage: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  value: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Select;
```